# How to measure distances in a image with python?

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I was wondering how can I measure distances in a image with python. Let's say I have a image of a coin, and I want to take a measure of the coin from a point A to a point B. What type of packages would I need to be looking into? And if I want that measure to be calibrated by some reference measure so I can get the real measurement of the distance I am getting? Sorry if my question is confusing. I want to develop a desktop application with Qt.

Comment: You may try to use (PIL + OpenCV + Numpy) in your project.

Comment: the biggest problem being to determine the scale: how big is a pixel in reality. This will 100% depend on the distance to the object, the sensor, the focal length, the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some info, so I did the best that I could in answering your question. In formulating my answer, I have taken the assumption that when you say "distances," you mean distances in reality, such as meters, feet, lightyears, etc.

I have a method that works only for "flat" images (meaning, the picture is not captured from the side) but works nonetheless. It relies on the [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/) and [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/) libraries – PIL for loading the image into Python, and NumPy for converting it into a relatively easy-to-use 3-dimensional array.

The script uses two given points and the distance formula to calculate the distance between the two points on the image in pixels. To get the real units, divide the distance by the image's width, resulting in a number between 0 and 1, and multiply that number by the width of the image in reality – that is, the span of the rightmost and leftmost pixels of the image in real life, like 30 centimeters or 2.3 miles.

[Click here](https://repl.it/@avivshai/DistanceOnImage) for a REPL so you can try it for yourself.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt

img = Image.open("my_picture.jpg")
pixels = np.array(img)

width, height, channels = pixels.shape

actual_width = ...
actual_units = ...

(x1, y1) = ...
(x2, y2) = ...

pixel_distance = sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)

actual_distance = (pixel_distance / width) * actual_width

print(f"The distance between the two points is about {actual_distance:.3f} {actual_units}")
```

Side note: the final line contains an f-string, which was only added in Python version 3.6.

Please let me know if this is not what you were asking for or if there is any other way I can help.

Comment: I am sorry about the lack of info. You are right, I meant real distances, in my case I'll be measuring objects with micrometers in length. The goal is to measure based on a calibration scale, a line in the picture that has exactly 1 micrometer for example, and then I will need to measure basically two distances between 3 points. A to Center (1st distance) B to Center ( second distance) and store those measures to use in some calculations later, but I need the real values instead of the pixel values, the images will be flat, thats 100% sure, it will be top view. Thank you for your answer.